# nullptr as a template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, nullptr

I have a template like:

```
template <class A, class B>
void func(A* a, B* b){
  ...
}
```

In some cases it happens that parameter `B* b` is not needed and therefore, I try to use a nullptr:

```
MyA a;
func(&a, nullptr);
```

The compiler doesn't like that since `nullptr` somehow is not a type.

How can I deal with that situation? The only idea is to just use a dummy type for that case.

Comment: `nullptr` is of type `nullptr_t`.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: `nullptr` is not a pointer, its type is `nullptr_t`, which cannot be matched with `B*`, but you can manually do so by `func(&c, (int*)nullptr);`, it's not optimal for user though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that `nullptr` is not actually a pointer, but an object of type `nullptr_t`. So it cannot match either `A*` or `B*`.  One option would be to provide an overload to specifically handle `nullptr_t`.

```
template<class A>
void func(A* a, nullptr_t)
{
    func(a, (int*)nullptr);
}
```

If you also want to allow the first argument to be `nullptr`, you can provide 2 more overloads. One to handle just the first argument, and one to handle both.

```
template<class B>
void func(nullptr_t, B* b)
{
    func((int*)nullptr, b);
}

void func(nullptr_t, nullptr_t)
{
    func((int*)nullptr, (int*)nullptr);
}
```

For any more arguments, this approach becomes unfeasible without code generation, as the number of overloads required is an exponential function of the number of arguments. In that case, I would recommend jrok's approach.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the overloading as suggested by [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30697237/947836), another option is conditionaly enabling the function if the types `A` and `B` are either a pointer or `std::nullptr_t`:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_pointer : std::integral_constant<bool,
                        std::is_pointer<T>::value ||
                        std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value    
                    >
{};

template <class A, class B>
typename std::enable_if<
   is_pointer<A>::value && is_pointer<B>::value
>::type
func(A a, B b) { }
```

But sometimes the simplest is the best, so maybe a second overload `template<class A> func(A*);` will do the job.

Comment: ``nullptr`` will not work if we need to use some pointer related actions on b(e.g. ``*b``, ``b->foo``), in this case we may need another type cast on ``b``.

Answer (score 0):

when you want to call that function, you can do the following instead of the other ways:

```
    func<a, b>(var_a, nullptr);
```

by doing this, you just pass your template to function and you can have your own type

Answer (score 0):

This is just another hacky way of doing it, but it works:

```
T* tNullptr = nullptr;
functionWithTemplate(otherArgument1, tNullptr)
```